# Convexity of $A \mapsto |A^{T}A|^{2}$

Tags: convex-analysis

This is an extension to [Convexity of $|A^TA|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3216604). Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and let $|\cdot|$ denote the Frobenius (matrix) norm. Define function $f : \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(A) := |A^{T} A|^{2}$. Is $f$ **convex**?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^2$ is convex and increasing, also $g(A) = \lvert A^T A\rvert$  is convex, therefore $h(A)=f(g(A)) = \lvert A^T A\rvert^2$ is convex by [composition rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880725/are-the-standard-rules-for-determining-convexity-of-composition-of-2-functions-a).